# use utf 8 in url, codeigniter ,seo

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, utf-8

im building a website and i want to use utf 8 characters in the url ive looked in some places but i didnt got the answer i need so i have few questions about it.

im using codeigniter and the website im building have a articles i want to send the article title (not in english) in the url

domain.com/ctrl/articles/articleTitle(not in english)

1. is it or is it not good for SEO to use this kinds of urls in case my visitors gone a search not in english
2. how do i do it?

thank you all for your answers.

Comment: What is your problem for use it?

Comment: Asking for SEO advice is off-topic here. You might want to [edit] your question and only ask about how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put this line in your controller constructor it forces everything to be utf-8

```
class Article extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    // set all to utf-8 
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  } 

// controller methods etc
```

the links will be output in your view files -- this insures that all your text including links will be output in utf-8 encoding. the other side of this is characters that are not allowed in the url by default by codeigniter -- in application/config/config.php check out

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars']
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not one of SEO here.  Google wont be fussy about utf8 characters in urls tho there are compatibility issues with very old browsers.

If you are talking about e.g. scandinavian languages who have just a few extra characters, google is clever enough to convert search terms e.g. which contain 'bär' to match pages called 'bar' and vice versa.  So for this type of language it is probably not worth the extra hassle of putting utf8 characters in the url.  But if you are talking about chinese or something, then here is a way of doing it.

The issue is that codeigniter uses the url to determine which class and functions to execute, and that is restricted to a-zA-Z_ in php5 (i think).  This guy says it's not an easy task but details an aproach which seems to have worked.

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/146840/#717001

> You can enable UTF-8 characters by entering them into the
>   allowed_chars_list in config.php then set up routes for your *Foreign*
>   URL segments, or by patching the router to convert UTF-8 characters to
>   their nearest a-z characters perhaps?

Basically rewrite the utf8 urls so they are translated to normal characters internally so the correct functions are found.